# How to separate label and the text field in alpacajs

Tags: alpacajs

I am using alpacajs to render a form automatically.
I want to separate the label and the input so as to set them under separate column.
Like

COL1 | COL2

lastname | lname textbox

firstname | fname textbox

This can't be achieved as i don't have any options while specifying schema/options.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have this kind of presentation, alpaca have a buil-in view template for that, you could use the "bootstrap-edit-horizontal".

```
"view": "bootstrap-edit-horizontal"
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/dcx7bb5q/1/).

Tell me if you want something else :)

Comment: Sorry, the final obtained view with your parameter is not what i want. I get only a single column with two rows. Whereas i would like to have 2 cols and a single row.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
Have you tried to enlarge the preview window in jsfiddle?
http://imgur.com/AiDWwIL